# $G_1$-Scalar factors for Clebsch-Gordan coefficients for $ U(n)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, lie-groups

When evaluating the $G_1$ scalar factors for CGC's of $U(n)$ it seems that some of the factors are undefined. The explicit formula for the evaluation of the scalar factors is Eq. (6) in 18.2.8 of N.J. Vilenkin and A.U. Klimyk, *Representation of Lie Groups and Special Functions*, vol. 3, page 382.

As far as I can see, $l_{s,n}-l_{k,n-1}$ can turn to zero, if $k=s$ and the elements of the Gelfand-Zeitlin pattern $m_{s,n}=m_{s,n-1}=0$, which gives (-1)! which is undefined. What am I overlooking here?

Comment: Can you provide eq. (6)? I don't have the reference at hand. And what are $G_1$ factors?